# Using RegularExpressionValidator to display asterisk on the next label

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a request that I’m having difficulty working out…
Once the 'Name' field is completed, the 5 labels below it should show a red asterisk

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qayrg.png)

I’ve added a RegularExpressionValidator which dynamically displays a red asterisk next the name label once the textbox is populated and tabbed, however this isn’t what’s required.

RegularExpressionValidator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewDos" Display="Dynamic" CssClass=" mandatory" ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,1})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

ASP

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNumCurStudentsDos" Text="Number of Current PGR students supervised"></asp:Label>
```

CSS

```css
.mandatory:after
{
    content:' *';
    color:red
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how I can populate my CSS class next the 5 labels once the Name text box has been populated?

Answer (score 0):

Placing the RegularExpressionValidator within each label `<td> </td>` works

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewDos"
  Display="Dynamic" CssClass=" mandatory" ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,1})$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```